# Como identificar a quantidade de palavras no código R?

Tags: r

Ao analisar frases com alterações de caixa, pontuações e palavras repetidas, como identificar a quantidade de palavras repetidas em casos que se inclui a acentuação?

```
text2 <- "A vaca malHada foi molhADA por outra VACA , MOLhada e MALhaDa ."
nchar(text2 == "malhada")
```

Ao testar com a função `grep` ela não me retorna a quantidade adequada. Nem com o `nchar`, para buscar por exemplo a palavra `"malhada"` ou `"vaca"`.

Answer (score 2):

Usando `grep`: quebre a *string* e use a opção `ignore.case = TRUE`:

```
text2 <- "A vaca malHada foi molhADA por outra VACA , MOLhada e MALhaDa ."

x <- strsplit(text2, "\\s")[[1]]

grep("malhada", x, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "malHada" "MALhaDa"

length(grep("malhada", x, TRUE))
#> [1] 2
```

Se quiser contar palavras ignorando caixa e acentuação, pode usar `stringi::stri_trans_general` para remover as acentuações primeiro:

```
library(stringi)

text3 <- "A vaca malHada foi môlhADA por outra VACA , MOLhada e MÁLhaDa ."

y <- strsplit(stri_trans_general(text3, "Latin-ASCII"), "\\s")[[1]]

length(grep("malhada", y, TRUE))
#> [1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
```

Uma sugestão usando o `tidytext::unnest_tokens()`:

```
text2 <- "A vaca malHada foi molhADA por outra VACA , MOLhada e MALhaDa ."
```

Primeiro, precisamos converter para um formato "tibble", usando o `as_tibble()`.

Em seguida, aplica-se a função `unnest_tokens()` que, por padrão, separa as palavras e as converte para minúsculas e remove pontuações.

No seu exemplo, não há palavras com acentos. Mas se houvesse, uma opção para retirá-los seria usar a função `abjutils::rm_accent()`;

E, finalmente, contam-se as palavras com a função `count()`

```
text2 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest_tokens(input = value, output = words) %>% 
  mutate(words = abjutils::rm_accent(words)) %>% 
  count(words)


# A tibble: 8 × 2
  words       n
  <chr>   <int>
1 a           1
2 e           1
3 foi         1
4 malhada     2
5 molhada     2
6 outra       1
7 por         1
8 vaca        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma vantagem da linguagem R é você poder executar e analisar o resultado de cada passo do que está fazendo. Observe que:

```
nchar(text2 == "malhada")

nchar(text2 == text2)
```

Resulta em 5 e 4, respectivamente, mas ele está contando o número de caracteres da resposta, que é `false` e `true`.

Para obter o que deseja, você precisa desenvolver vários passos, como abaixo.

```
text2 <- "A vaca malHada foi molhADA por outra VACA , MOLhada e MALhaDa ."
text2 <- tolower(text2) # coloca todas as letras em caixa baixa
text2 <- gsub(",", "", text2) # remove a vírgula
text2 <- gsub("\\.", "", text2) # remove os pontos
text2 <- gsub("  ", " ", text2) # remove espaços duplos
text2 <- trimws(text2) # remove espaço no começo ou fim

library(stringr)
words <- str_split(text2, " ")[[1]] # divide a string nos espaços
table(words) # monta a tabela de frequência
```

---

```
  a       e     foi malhada molhada   outra     por    vaca 
  1       1       1       2       2       1       1       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Quebrando o problema em partes:

```
library(stringr)
```

1. Transforme a frase em um vetor

```
vetor <- str_extract_all(text2, "\\w+")[[1]]
```

2. Verificando se a "agulha" está no palheiro

```
vetor_TF <- str_detect(vetor, regex("malhada", ignore_case = TRUE))
```

3. Contando os valores TRUE

```
qtd_T <- length(which(vetor_TF))
```

Ou tudo em uma linha

```
length(which(str_detect(str_extract_all(text2, "\\w+")[[1]], regex("malhada", ignore_case = TRUE))))
```

Outra opção mais simples

```
str_count(tolower(text2), "malhada")
```

Comment: Dei voto positivo, mas faltou indicar a biblioteca utilizada (stringr).